# Set outlet on programmatically UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

How to set an outlet on an UIBarButtonItem. I have programmatically maked this button and now i can not connect the outlet. Is there a code for connecting outlets?

Making the button:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 28);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donebutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(releaseKeyboard) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[barButton1 setCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton1;
```

Selector:

```
-(void)releaseKeyboard {

[text resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Where the problem is:

```
-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSLog(@"Keyboard hide");
    barButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

barButton is not connected to an outlet, because i can't select anything in the IB.

Comment: If you really created this programmatically, you should have already specified a target and an action during initialization. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I thought so too, but than i'm getting the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'button'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so instead of

```
barButton.enabled = NO;
```

use

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

That's because you don't own the reference to `barButton1` anymore (you're in another function -- another context), let alone `barButton`.

Comment: And how about (multiple) `textfields`? how to get the one you want without affecting the other textfields? And is there a way to own the reference again so we can use the names like `barButton1` in another function again?

Answer (score 1):

"Connecting outlets" is a concept solely related to Interface Builder. You don't "connect outlets" when you create views by code, rather you setup the target-action mechanism ad you did.

Maybe try instanciating the BarButtonItem with `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]` ?

Comment: hmm ok. I add some more code, so maybe you get a better explanation of my problem.